# Can't activate child theme in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My site is http://test.javatutorialhub.com/

I have to create a child theme for a theme called udesign.

I have done the necessary things. But when I activate the child theme I get a message saying "this theme requires parent theme".

Here is my code of functions.php

```
<?php

/*
* Add your own functions here. You can also copy some of the theme functions into this file. 
* Wordpress will use those functions instead of the original functions then.
*/
```

and here is code of style.css

```
/*
 Theme Name:     U-design Child Theme
 Theme URI:      http://themeforest.net/item/udesign-wordpress-theme/253220?ref=internq7
 Description:    A slick, powerful and clean theme.
 Author:         Andon
 Author URI:     http://themeforest.net/user/internq7/portfolio?ref=internq7
 Template:       u-design
 Version:        2.1.0

*/
```

So what have I done wrong?

Note: someone said to me that you can not activate child theme. Is it true? Please help.

Comment: very obvious thing but  `u-design` theme in your wordpress ? and other thing is add `@import url("../u-design/style.css");`

Comment: What do you want to accomplish in functions.php? Also, as @wordpresser said you're missing a line in your style.css file in the child theme folder. It is not true that you cannot activate a child theme. Everything just needs to be in the right place. Look over the [instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) again and make sure you didn't miss any steps.

Comment: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/child-themes-basics-and-creating-child-themes-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have to create a child theme for a theme **called** udesign.

your css header tag

> Template:       **u-design**

Those two does not match, that is why it is not working (assuming from information provided)

Into the css header keyword `template` put always a folder name of your parent theme